# How to add new persistent disk without rebooting the server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, debian-jessie, fstab

I've got a running instance on GCP and would like to add another persistent disk into it. But it will not show up.

It's an `n1-standard-1` instance with a 10 GB storage (named `s03`). I created another storage `disk-1` and mounted it. Then I created `disk-2`.

[image: disks]

Sadly the new one won't show up at `ls /dev/disk/by-id` like mentioned in the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk).

[image: shell]

[image: fdisk]

I rebooted the system and checked the logs, but can't find any issues why `disk-2` will not show up. Any ideas?

Comment: Does it show in dmesg? If not, something is wrong.

Comment: looks like i need to restart. :( dmesg shows `(Nothing has been logged yet.)`

Comment: I'm not sure if GCP/GCE does persistent disks via the hypervisor as a block device or maybe just as an NFS share, but if it's supposed to be a block device a VM reboot will be needed since it apparently doesn't do hotplug support.

Comment: I created a Debian 8 VM and attached the disk. It was actually recognized without the need to reboot the system. 
 ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root xx -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root xx -> ../../sdb
I would try detaching and [re-attaching](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/attach-disk) the disk using the CLI. If something is failing you might get more information than from the WUI.  How many disks are attached to your VM?  [Small VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types)
 will not support more than 4 disks and a maximum size of 3TB

Comment: The first disk connected without any problems. The second (so there is a total of 3 with the instance-storage itself) will now show up. I deleted `disk-2` and created it, rebooted the system - but nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually very simple.
Your screenshot shows that your disk-2 is not attached to your VM instance.
It should look like this

[image]

And now compare to what you posted.

So what you need to do is this:

1. Head to "VM Instances"
2. Click on your Instance
3. In the top click on Edit

[image]

4. Scroll down to "Additional disks" section and click Add

[image]

5. Select your disk from the drop down menu

[image]

6. Scroll down to the bottom and click Save.

It should now show up as sdc in the dmesg output

[image]

or in the fdisk -l

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After some testing, I believe your issue is related to the use of a blank disk. In my case, I attached to the VM one blank disk and one formatted disk. The formatted disk got recognized as ¨/dev/sdc1¨ but the blank disk was not showing.

i.e

```
ls -altr /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov 11 16:50 40206d63-43a8-4d1c-8588-581cefb022a3 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov 11 17:34 7f63bd57-6ccd-4cea-b0f0-9544870bf67a -> ../../sdc1
```

¨fdisk -l¨ showed the disk was not partitioned but confirmed it was attached to the VM as /dev/sdb

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
.....
/dev/sda1  *     4096 20971519 20967424  10G 83 Linux
Disk /dev/sdb: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/sdc: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
.....
/dev/sdc1  *     2048 20971519 20969472  10G 83 Linux
```

I used ¨fdisk /dev/sdb¨ to create a partition table, then ¨fdisk -l¨ displayed

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 10 GiB, 10737418240 bytes, 20971520 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x5808f242

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 20971519 20969472  10G 83 Linux
```

As per [the document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#formatting) I formatted the disk

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -F -E lazy_itable_init=0,lazy_journal_init=0,discard /dev/sdb1
```

Finally the disk showed

```
ls -altr /dev/disk/by-uuid/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov 11 16:50 40206d63-43a8-4d1c-8588-581cefb022a3 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Nov 11 17:34 7f63bd57-6ccd-4cea-b0f0-9544870bf67a -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Nov 11 18:09 460a2e04-0f66-42d4-b9cc-8567aa6ee7b8 -> ../../sdb1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time investigating the issue. Sadly there's no `sdc` or anything else for me in fdisk. The 10GB drive is still missing. I updated my question with another screenshot of fdisk.

Comment: It is no surprise you need to create a file system before the partition shows up in `/dev/disk/by-uuid`. After all the only UUID the partition has is the one generated by `mkfs.ext4`.

Comment: how to create a partition of something not even showing in fdisk?

Comment: If you run `gcloud compute instances describe NAME  --zone ZONE` How many disks do you see attached? What are the details of the disks being used? i.e interface type, size, SSD, Standard?. Are these disks blank? I suggest checking the messages on your VM [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console) when you attach the disk. You should see errors or something like
`Nov 14 16:36:07 [8965079.397764] sd 0:0:3:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk`
If you spin a new VM using a public image and new disks, does this happen? What kind of VM are you using?